# VsCode debugging on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, xdebug

working on ubuntu 19.10 and trying to get started with debugging my code in VScode, but after installing an extension - nothing works(buttons are disabled).

Using php7.3, in php.ini added several lines:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000`
```

apache2 installed, but for now use build-in web server
my php.ini config sees the params i've added also.
the .json file VScode made itself is:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration

```
zend_extension=<path_of_the_extension>
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_timeout = 500
```

Also be sure that the `php.ini` file is the right one, using `phpinfo();` function. The first lines show the path

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.7

...
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
...
```

In my case, this configuration was written in `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini` instead of the `php.ini` because XDebug was installed in Ubuntu from repositories